# perl cgi cannot print elements from php checkbox array

Tags: php, perl, cgi

I had an HTML form that sent checkbox values to a Perl CGI script as an Array. However, since the site was rebuilt using mainly PHP, the checkbox array is handled differently. I have a PHP function that returns the form. It looks something like this:

```
<td>Profiles: </td>
<td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"oneconnect\" name=\"v1-profile[]\">OneConnect <br />
<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"http\" name=\"v1-profile[]\">HTTP <br />
<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"xforwardedfor\" name=\"v1-profile[]\">Xforwarded-for</td>
</tr>
```

I then send this to a Perl CGI script

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
my $q = new CGI;
my @profiles1 = $q->param("v1-profile");
```

When I try to print the elements of the array, I only see the word "Array" as the output.

```
foreach my $r (@profiles1) {
print "$r\n";
}
```

I have also tried a few things that did not work.

```
foreach my $r (@profiles1) {
foreach my $v (@$r) {
print "$v\n";
}
}
```

How would I access the elements of the "@profiles1" array?  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you seeing something like `ARRAY(0x27967ac)`? This is different from `Array` and means you have an array reference that simply needs dereferencing.

Answer (score 2):

The trailing `[]` on the variable name is a PHP-ism -- it's not standard, and isn't treated specially by Perl's CGI module (or anything other than PHP, really). If you can, remove it from the form. If not, you should be able to get at the parameter from Perl by including the brackets in the name:

```
my @profiles = $q->param("v1-profile[]");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I remove the "[]" from the PHP form, the CGI script does function. However, if you select multiple checkboxes, I only see 1 element sent to the CGI script. I need multiple checkboxes. I also tried adding the "[]" to the param name as you suggested, but that doesn't work. (I don't even see the word "Array" output at that time. Again, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @dars33 — Both this and your original code appear to be getting the result in list context, so it should give you the values of all the checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is. It seems to work fine for me. Here's the little test rig I built.

test.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/form">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Profiles: </td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" value="oneconnect" name="v1-profile[]">OneConnect <br />
          <input type="checkbox" value="http" name="v1-profile[]">HTTP <br />
          <input type="checkbox" value="xforwardedfor" name="v1-profile[]">Xforwarded-for<br />
          <input type="submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

cgi-bin/form:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;

print $q->header(-type => 'text/plain');

my @profiles = $q->param('v1-profile[]');

foreach (@profiles) {
  print "$_\n";
}
```

And I see exactly what I expect. Each checkbox I check is displayed in the output.

One thing to check. What does your URL look like once you have submitted the form? Mine looks like this (with two checkboxes checked).

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/form?v1-profile%5B%5D=oneconnect&v1-profile%5B%5D=xforwardedfor
```

Notice that the square brackets in the input names have been URL-encoded. That's what should happen.

So the question is, how does this differ from your set-up?